# Зависает framebuffer

Tags: linux

Использую *mplayer* или *fbi* через *framebuffer* в *Centos 7* (`init 3`).

Если в консоли дать команду `kill -9 pid_процесса`, часто картинка зависает. Спасает переключение на другую консоль через <kbd>Alt + Fn</kbd>.

Как можно очистить *framebuffer* и вернуть изображение с *tty*? Нужен аналог команды *clear*, но только для *framebuffer*.

Answer (score 1):

вот [здесь](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=35347) пишут, что помогает только запись нулей напрямую во *framebuffer*:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/fb0
```

я думаю, что бесконечно (как это будет делать данная команда) записывать не нужно. следует экспериментально установить, сколько блоков (например, по одному килобайту — `1K`) будет достаточно для полной очистки экрана:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/fb0 bs=1K count=количество_блоков
```